How do I get the Tab-bar of the lightning-tabset component to set when the variable used to define the tabs is updated?
I have a custom object called Testing Stepthat has child Testing Steps. I have a LWC that uses a wired method to call an apex method that returns a list of Testing Steps and their children. I put the list into a variable and use that variable to dynamically create <lightning-tab>s in a <lightning-tabset>. The content of each tab is a datatable with the child Testing Steps for the current tab/Testing Step.
I want to be able to reorder the tabs, so I added some left/right buttons that when clicked reorder the parent Testing Step Ids, and sends that to an Apex Method that updates the Order fields of all the parent Testing Steps. In the promise of that method I call refreshApex() on the variable that contains the results of the original wired method that returns the parent Testing Steps.
While this does result in the tab content updating (I concatenate the Order value to the title of the tab in the content and I see the Order change after the refreshApex() method gets called), however, the tabs in the tab bar along the top do not reorder themselves. The tab bar is not a lightning component, the <lightning-tabset> component builds it from the <lightning-tab>s. I can get the tab bar to refresh if I clear the variable that stores the parent Testing Steps before calling refreshApex(), but then the content of the tabs do not render.
I did not including code here because my above description is a simplification that only deals with the issue which isn't a code issue. The problem is that the tab bar of the <lightning-tabset> does not get rerendered when the variable driving the tabset gets changed. I will include code if anyone wants, but it's pretty ugly and some of my naming conventions border on lunacy.
TL;DR: Does anyone know a trick to force the entire <lightning-tabset>, including the tab-bar, to rerender with updated data?

you have @track on the variable that stores result or you @refreshApex?
